# My div gets pushed out because of expanding on hover

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, expand

My actie tab/div gets pushed out if I hover on another div. I want it to just get pushed on the side of the screen when you hover on another div. you might not see it get pushed out because the .top_menu is on overflow:hidden; but if you look you can see it is not smooth when you hover on a tab/div.

Please tell me how to fix this or explain to me how to do this better. I want the top bar to have two big divs on the 2 sides and smaller ones in the middle. Like when you see it when you don't hover on them. But I also want to be able to expand them with the hover.

But I don't want it to zoom on hover because I'm planning on putting images inside the divs.

EDIT: i also want it to use the whole top bar otherwise i have these weird black bars at the side if i put in a white image in one of the 2 bigger tabs.

```js
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
  $('.top_menu').toggleClass('tiny', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  background-position: center;
}
.content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.80);
}
.top_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 500ms, background 500ms;
}
.top_menu.tiny {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.top_home {
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: rgba(58, 185, 254, 1.00);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 500ms;
  transition: width 500ms;
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms;
  -webkit-transition: width 500ms;
  display: inline-block;
}
.top_home:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
}
.top_button {
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: rgba(58, 185, 254, 1.00);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 500ms;
  transition: width 500ms;
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms;
  -webkit-transition: width 500ms;
  display: inline-block;
}
.top_button:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
}
.top_actie {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 500ms;
  transition: width 500ms;
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms;
  -webkit-transition: width 500ms;
  display: inline-block;
}
.top_actie:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top_menu">

  <div class="top_home">Home</div>
  <div class="top_button">stuff</div>
  <div class="top_button">stuff</div>
  <div class="top_button">stuff</div>
  <div class="top_button">stuff</div>
  <div class="top_button">stuff</div>
  <div class="top_actie">Actie!</div>

</div>
<div class="content">
  DutchWilliam
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your `actie div` must go where? When I see your fiddle, you have a `home` and `actie` tab, wich are larger then the ones in the middel. Or is the `actie`tab, not a tab?

Comment: wel yeah its a tab. but if you hover on one of the other tab. the actie tabs gets pushed down. but euhm a tab is what you see and it is a div in the code rly isnt it?? tab or div isnt it the same

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 buttons (10% x 5 = 50%) and 2 bigger buttons (20% x 2 = 40%). So your buttons use 90% of your total width. When you hoover, you add an additional 10% to the width. So 90% + 10% = 100% of the width you can use. But here is the problem. You also have borders between your buttons with a width of 2px each. So you have an additional 10px. 100% + 10px = 100+%, so it doesn't fit.

the solution: in stat of adding an extra 10% width when you hover a button (big or small), add like 8% or something.

```
.top_home:hover {
  width: 28%;
}

.top_actie:hover {
  width: 28%;
}

.top_button:hover {
  width: 18%;
}
```

Comment: yes but than i have these black bars on the side of the 2 big buttons when i put say a white picture in it. and i want it to use the whole top bar

Comment: Your whole jsfiddle is black, so I don't know what you mean by that? Je mag het van mij ook in het Nederlands uitleggen als dat makkelijker is

Comment: nou ik heb boven aan er nu ook bijgezet dat ik van plan ben plaatjes in de tabs/buttons/div's te doen. als ik daar een plaatje in zet die bijv. wit is dan ziet het er niet uit.(i changed the color of the home div to gray imagine that that is a picture)

Comment: Ja, maar die zwarte balken zijn toch logisch omdat de tabjes breder worden? Daarnaast, krijgt elke tab een ander kleurtje, of krijgen ze allemaal dezelfde kleur?

Comment: ja het is logisch maar ik wil zeg maar dat het tabje of over de andere heen gaat of de andere kleiner maakt. en ze worden allemaal een andere kleur.

Comment: jij hebt elke tab 10% of 20% gemaakt, dus dat is de standaard. Als jij met je muis over een tabje gaat, worden andere niet kleiner, maar die tab groter. Daarnaast schuift de rest van de tabjes op (de tabjes gaan niet over elkaar heen). Als jij een afbeelding plaatst (met doorzichtige achtergrond, een .png) in het "normale tabje" (die 10% breed is) met css (background-image) en het tabje een achtergrondkleur geeft (background-color). Zou je geen problemen moeten hebben.

Comment: nee maar dat wil ik juist voor elkaar krijgen. op een of andere manier de andere kleiner of eroverheen laten gaan zodat ik er gewoon een normaal plaatje in kan zetten.

Comment: Zoiets zou je denk ik kunnen doen met javascript. Ik zou een nieuwe vraag aanmaken waarin je die vraag stelt. Want nu was je hoofdvraag hoe je kan voorkomen dat je "actie knop" onder de rest van je buttons schuift

Comment: ja ik dacht al zoeits maar nou ja dan maar in de wereld van jquery of javascript duiken bedankt in ieder geval